# initializing combineLatest with default Value

Tags: angular, rxjs

According to the documentation on the combineLatest, I cant initialize it on startup to contain values. Which results in my component being empty. Is there any way around this so that the this.projects is shown by default?

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filtered =
      combineLatest(of(this.projects), this.searchService.observable)
        .pipe(
          map(([projects, searchString]: [{ name: string, preview: string, text: string }[], string]) =>
            projects.filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase()))
          ));

    this.filtered.subscribe();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `startWith` operator.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.filtered =
      combineLatest(of(this.projects), this.searchService.observable.pipe(startWith('')))
        .pipe(
          map(([projects, searchString]: [{ name: string, preview: string, text: string }[], string]) =>
            projects.filter(x => x.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase()))
          ));

    this.filtered.subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: I was trying to do the startwith in the wrong location... I tried to put it as a part of the pipe, which did not work. Thank you.